# How do i port forward Using huawei 5g cpe pro 2 For a remote access tool

Tags: networking, router, remote-desktop, port-forwarding, modem

So i use huawei 5g cpe pro 2
and its asking me to make one i need to write the
Name
Protocol
Remote host
WAN Port
DEVICE
LAN Port
My ip4 adress is :  192.168.8.53
In the remote access tool Its asking me to write the ip and port
Please help im new
Also Im doing the remote access tool to troll my friends a lil bit

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser . Your question as is not very legible, and it's hard to make out what your scenario is, what you're trying to do, and what the issue you're having with it. Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1784158/edit) and include more details and a better description of your issue.

Comment: in my experience, most providers of mobile internet do it in such a way that incoming connections are not possible, therefore, no amount of port forwarding will help